# How to get OpenVPN details from macOS to iOS

Tags: iphone, network, vpn, ios

I have a VPN which I connect to on my MacBook with Tunnelblick. I would like to setup my iPhone 6 to connect to the same VPN, however I am struggling to find an app or way to do this.

In Tunnelblick, I can see the configuration file which looks like this:

```
dev tun
proto udp
remote vpn.crmpicco.co.uk 1194
cipher AES-128-CBC
auth SHA1
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
client
verb 3
auth-user-pass
<ca>
 [Security-related line(s) omitted]
</ca>
<cert>
 [Security-related line(s) omitted]
</cert>

<key>
 [Security-related line(s) omitted]
</key>
```

Can anyone advise me on how to connect to this VPN on iOS?

Comment: not *specifically* but have you gone into Settings > VPN and set it up there? you don't always need an app. IOS supports IKEv2, IPSec & L2TP VPNs out of the box. You will need connection info, username, authentication (cert or password). Your VPN provider should have that info.

Comment: The VPN is OpenVPN which I don't see listed. I've updated my question as this is important.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand your question correctly, you can use iTunes on the MacBook to transfer the profile you're using into OpenVPN on your iPhone.

Broadly speaking, you need to:

1. Download and install the [OpenVPN](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/openvpn-connect/id590379981?mt=8) app from the app store onto your iPhone
2. Locate the OpenVPN config file (it should have a .ovpn extension) you downloaded on your MacBook so you know where it is
3. Connect your iPhone to your MacBook
4. Launch iTunes
5. Select your iPhone (within iTunes)
6. Click on *Apps* on the left-hand menu
7. Scroll to the bottom in the main window (on the right-hand side) and click on the OpenVPN icon in the *Apps* box
8. Drag and drop the OpenVPN config file (the one you located at Step 2) into the *OpenVPN Documents* box
9. Click on <kbd>Done</kbd>
10. Open the OpenVPN app on your iPhone
11. You should now see the new certificate listed
12. Click on the green <kbd>+</kbd> sign
13. Enter your username, password etc
14. Tap on the Save toggle

Now when you want to connect to the VPN from your iPhone, just tap on the toggle that appears below the *Disconnected* label. You *should* be connected shortly thereafter.